# Diagnosing application causing a system crash

Tags: linux, opengl, crash, operating-system, gpu

I noticed recently that adding meshes that were too large to a program I am working on caused my machine to crash.

Since everything seems to be working fine before the crash, and I don't get a segmentation fault but rather a full system crash, I suspect the error is caused by my application demanding too much power from the GPU and thus causing insuficient power in my setup.

Nvidia-smi reports the following before a crash:

[image]

However my power supply is a 750B EVGA, so I am not sure if the problem actually comes from insufficient power.

The program runs fine with small meshes (10 000 ish triangles). It crashed with the crytek sponza scene (280 000 ish triangles).

How can I diagnose what actually causes the system crash?

Comment: Did you try your application on another PC?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't had the opportunity

Comment: What does "and I don't get a segmentation fault but rather a full system crash" actually mean. Nothing in your description suggests that to be a power issue.

Comment: it means that when I run my prgram,a fter 1 minut the system reboots